# Results dissapearing on refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, backbone.js

After the user submits a form a new view for the results will be displayed. The results view will use the form fields to create a JSON object, send the JSON with an ajax request to the server and receive a JSON response that has all of the results. The results are then rendered with the view. This all works fine but when the results page is refreshed all of the results are gone. How would I make it so that my results will continue to show up after I refresh the page? What I'm trying to do now is alter the URL so that it will contain the query and then the results view will use the URL to form a request and send it to the server. Is this the recommended course of action for what I'm trying to achieve here? Thanks.

Comment: could store them in session or if not sensitive data can store in browser localStorage

Comment: local storage is definitely the way to go! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the function which calls the ajax request on page load.. your values are getting lost as it will reset to default `undefined/null` etc when the user loads the page again.

If you want the onload method to take parameters, you can do something similar to this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // put something here so the function will not call if the ajax call has not been called beforee
  yourFunction(param1, param2);
};
```

This onload will call the function for you therefore no matter what running the ajax call each time.

of course you will need validation so it does not call that function if the ajax request has not been used before.i.e. something in the query string when its successful etc.

Comment: I've tried to do this but the problem is that my query (which is get using jquery) is being reset to default and without knowing the query I can't make the request.